# Relatório Jasper reclamando de propriedade não existente

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jasper

[RESOLVIDO] Galera, tenho um relatório e me deparo com a seguinte situação:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'acompanhamentoPorObra' on class 'class br.com.okds.evop.acompanhamento.ent.aditivo.AditivoDeContrato'
```

Ele diz que a propriedade não existe na entidade do objeto em questão, não existe mesmo essa propriedade e nem a uso no meu relatório.
O mesmo poderia ser algum field que a entidade usa pra fazer alguma operação, porém vasculhei meu código e realmente não existe. 
Alguém já passou pelo mesmo problema?
Agradecido desde já! Abraço!

Answer (score 0):

[RESOLVIDO] Era a entidade da minha pesquisa que estava totalmente errado, 
ai quando mandava gerar o relatório o mesmo pegava um .jasper totalmente diferente do qual eu preparei. Valeu!